# Развертывание приложения  silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, c#

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажете как развернуть приложение Silverlight?  Что копировать в корневую папку.? Получается что у проекта 2 солюшена один веб сервис и сама клиентская часть. В какой иерархии и что переносить?

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев развертывание собственно Silverlight сводится к копированию XAP архива и HTML страниц в то место на веб-сервере, откуда они будут отдаваться.

И еще надо, чтобы веб-сервер правильно отрабатывал MIME-типы для Silverlight (обычно это уже настроено хостером):

- .xaml application/xaml+xml
- .xap  application/x-silverlight-app
- .xbap application/x-ms-xbap

Answer (score 0):

Там есть руководство: [развертывание и локализация Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189057(v=vs.95).aspx).